# Azure error, cannot locate Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, azure, remote-debugging, azure-web-app-service

VS2017 C#

I have done this many times in the past on **another** PC.  Azure App set to debug, 2017, published debug version of code.

In VS 2017
Right-Clicked WebApp in Server Explorer / Attach Debugger.

```
Getting Config...
Warming up site...
Finding process to attach to...
```

Then a dialogue appears...

```
Server Explorer
    Unable to start program 'http://DaDeDa.azurewebsites.net'.
    Cannot locate Microsoft Internet Explorer.
```

I'm running this from a Windows 10 PC Edge/Chrome only.  I think I uninstalled Internet Explorer a while back.

Do I really need it to debug?  OR Is there a setting somewhere I can change to Edge/Chrome?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You could go to this [page](https://www.techbout.com/install-internet-explorer-on-windows-10-12490/) and reinstall Internet Explorer on Windows 10.

2.Or you could choose this way.Run **regedit** and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`.

If IEXPLORE.EXE doesn't exist, add it.Then change the (Default) REG_SZ value to `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` and create a new REG_SZ, name the value with **Path** and set the data to `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer`.

Here is the [reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCK2X.png).If you still have questions, please let me know.

Comment: (2) Fixed it, even though IEXPORE.EXE does not exist in that folder?!?!  (1) I could do because Internet Explorer is not listed in the features?!!?   Fixed though, thanks George.

Comment: Interestingly, then (even after doing 2), had the same problem when I tried to start the performance Profiler.  I found out how to re-install IE though (under apps/manage optional features) .  After doing that it all seems to work as expected.  Seems as though we cannot get rid of IE yet!

Comment: Not sure if this might give me side effects, but I created the IEXPLORE.EXE key and pointed it to chrome.exe